# How to wait for another action in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I have a few sagas that may finish and then `put` another action into the store.

Some sagas should only execute after others are executed: they must block, or wait until another one is finished.

Summarized as follows:

```
export function* authorize(action) {
  const { clientId } = action.data;

  const response = yield call(apiAuthorize, clientId);
  // Redux reducer picks this up and sets a token in storage. 
  yield put({ type: AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED, data: response.data.data });
}

export function* fetchMessages(action) {
  console.log(action);
  const { timelineId } = action.data;

  // how can we block this until either `token` is set (getToken returns non-null)
  //  or until AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED is sent?

  // The token set by AUTHORIZED_SUCCEEDED is read from the storage.
  // This will be null untill the AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED is handled by redux.
  // When null, the api-call will return a 401 so we want to block  untill we
  // have the token.
  const token = yield select(getToken);
  const response = yield call(apiFetchMessages, token);
  yield put({ type: MESSAGES_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, data: response.data.data });
}

export default function* appSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(AUTHORIZE_REQUESTED, authorize);
  yield takeEvery(MESSAGES_REQUESTED, fetchMessages);
}
```

I'm trying to maintain as little coupling between sagas, so bonus points for showing me a way to achieve this outside of the functions .

Please note that is a simplified version. In reality there are several such `fetchMessages` that may be triggered all of which should wait until the AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED comes in.

I can add a loop in the `fetchMessage()` function, but that feels icky. I'm not very familiar with Javascript, Redux, Saga or generator functions, so maybe this feeling is entirely wrong. I'm also not confident how to run a loop with a timeout with sagas' yield/select etc.

```
while (true) {
  const token = yield setTimeout(() => select(getToken), 1000);
  if (!!token) { 
    break;
  }
});
```

Another trick which works, but is cludgy, is to retry the fetchMessages api call on a 401.

```
try {
  const response = yield call(apiFetchMessages, token);
  yield put({ type: MESSAGES_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, data: response.data.data });
} catch (error) {
  if (error.request.status === 401) {
    yield put({ type: MESSAGES_REQUESTED, data: { blockId } });
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Is there an API or function for this in saga? Is this a proper pattern, or is my idea of blocking one action till another finishes wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the more coupled, but simpler solution - instead of using delay to wait in the cycle, you can use the `take` effect to wait for the `AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED` action:

```js
export function* fetchMessages(action) {
  const { timelineId } = action.data;

  // the cycle might not be needed if you are sure the 
  // AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED action is always dispatched with a valid token
  let token;
  while (true) {
     token = yield select(getToken);
     if (token) break;
     yield take(AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED);
  }

  const response = yield call(apiFetchMessages, token);
  yield put({ type: MESSAGES_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, data: response.data.data });
}
```

To make this less clunky, you can abstract this away into its own saga:

```js
export function* getTokenSaga() {
  let token;
  while (true) {
     token = yield select(getToken);
     if (token) break;
     yield take(AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED);
  }
  return token;
}

export function* fetchMessages(action) {
  const { timelineId } = action.data;

  const token = yield call(getTokenSaga);
  const response = yield call(apiFetchMessages, token);
  yield put({ type: MESSAGES_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, data: response.data.data });
}
```

Another way to approach this is to wrap the fetching method:

```js
export function* fetchWithToken(fetchFn, ...params) {
  let token;
  while (true) {
     token = yield select(getToken);
     if (token) break;
     yield take(AUTHORIZE_SUCCEEDED);
  }
  return yield call(fetchFn, token, ...params);
}

export function* fetchMessages(action) {
  const { timelineId } = action.data;

  const response = yield call(fetchWithToken, apiFetchMessages);
  yield put({ type: MESSAGES_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, data: response.data.data });
}
```

Completely different way to possibly solve this would be to change the architecture of your app to make sure no fetching action like `MESSAGES_REQUESTED` can be dispatched, until you have the token - for example to show loading until you get the token and only then allow the rest of the application to request additional data.

In such a case you could then modify the `fetch` method itself to get the token, since it would be always available:

```js
const loadData = (endpoint, payload) => {
  const token = getTokenSelector(store.getState())
  return fetch(endpoint, payload).then(...);
}

const apiFetchMessages = () => {
  return loadData('/messages');
}

export function* fetchMessages(action) {
  const { timelineId } = action.data;

  const response = yield call(apiFetchMessages);
  yield put({ type: MESSAGES_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, data: response.data.data });
}
```

If such a change is not possible in the place where you dispatch the actions, there is one more way I can think of how to make sure the token is always available without modifying the `fetchMessages` saga itself and that is to instead [buffer the other actions using `actionChannel` effect](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels/#using-the-actionchannel-effect), until you have the token - this can get bit more complicated since you need to think about what to buffer when:

```
export default function* appSaga() {
  // we buffer all fetching actions
  const channel = yield actionChannel([MESSAGES_REQUESTED, FOO_REQUESTED]);

  // then we block the saga until AUTHORIZE_REQUESTED is dispatched and processed
  const action = yield take(AUTHORIZE_REQUESTED);
  yield call(authorize, action);

  // There is multiple ways to process the buffer, for example
  // we can simply redispatch the actions once we started
  // listening for them using the `takeEvery` effect
  yield takeEvery(MESSAGES_REQUESTED, fetchMessages);
  yield takeEvery(FOO_REQUESTED, fetchFoo);
  while (const action = yield take(channel)) {
    yield put(action);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The missing piece for me was to call `take` inside a saga. I presumed, naively, that it was only used for binding generator functions to channels. But reading the docs more carefully I see I was wrong. Well, guess I shouldve RTFM. Extra thanks for the journey from coupled to app-wide solution!